# conda install -y -c conda-forge rdkit still askes for proceeding

Tags: conda, conda-forge

I am trying to automatically set up a conda environment using bash and therefore I want to run all conda install commands with the -y flag. My bash script looks like this:

```
read -p "Create new conda env (y/n)?" CONT

if [ "$CONT" == "n" ]; then
  echo "exit";
else
# user chooses to create conda env
# prompt user for conda env name
  echo "Creating new conda environment, choose name"
  read env_name
  echo "Name $input_variable was chosen";

  echo "installing base packages"
  conda create -y -c rdkit -n  $env_name rdkit
  eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
  conda activate $env_name
  conda install -y -c conda-forge rdkit
fi
```

Everything works fine including the "conda create -y -c rdkit -n $env_name rdkit"-line but the last line "conda isntall -y -c conda-forge rdkit" still askes for permission to proceed. Why does my -y flag not work on that line?

This is what the log looks like when I run my bash script:

```
make_conda_rdkit_env.sh: line 1: fg: no job control
Create new conda env (y/n)?y
Creating new conda environment, choose name
just_a_test_5
Name  was chosen
installing base packages
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/johanbr2/opt/anaconda3/envs/just_a_test_5

  added / updated specs:
    - rdkit


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               pkgs/main/osx-64::blas-1.0-mkl
  bottleneck         pkgs/main/osx-64::bottleneck-1.3.2-py37hf1fa96c_1
  bzip2              pkgs/main/osx-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h1de35cc_0
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/osx-64::ca-certificates-2021.10.26-hecd8cb5_2
  cairo              pkgs/main/osx-64::cairo-1.16.0-h8023c5d_1
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-64::certifi-2021.10.8-py37hecd8cb5_0
  fontconfig         pkgs/main/osx-64::fontconfig-2.13.1-ha9ee91d_0
  freetype           pkgs/main/osx-64::freetype-2.11.0-hd8bbffd_0
  gettext            pkgs/main/osx-64::gettext-0.21.0-h7535e17_0
  giflib             pkgs/main/osx-64::giflib-5.2.1-haf1e3a3_0
  glib               pkgs/main/osx-64::glib-2.69.1-hdf23fa2_0
  icu                pkgs/main/osx-64::icu-58.2-h0a44026_3
  intel-openmp       pkgs/main/osx-64::intel-openmp-2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_3538
  jpeg               pkgs/main/osx-64::jpeg-9d-h9ed2024_0
  lcms2              pkgs/main/osx-64::lcms2-2.12-hf1fd2bf_0
  libboost           pkgs/main/osx-64::libboost-1.73.0-hd4c2dcd_11
  libcxx             pkgs/main/osx-64::libcxx-12.0.0-h2f01273_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/osx-64::libffi-3.3-hb1e8313_2
  libiconv           pkgs/main/osx-64::libiconv-1.16-h1de35cc_0
  libpng             pkgs/main/osx-64::libpng-1.6.37-ha441bb4_0
  libtiff            pkgs/main/osx-64::libtiff-4.2.0-h87d7836_0
  libwebp            pkgs/main/osx-64::libwebp-1.2.0-hacca55c_0
  libwebp-base       pkgs/main/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.2.0-h9ed2024_0
  libxml2            pkgs/main/osx-64::libxml2-2.9.12-hcdb78fc_0
  llvm-openmp        pkgs/main/osx-64::llvm-openmp-12.0.0-h0dcd299_1
  lz4-c              pkgs/main/osx-64::lz4-c-1.9.3-h23ab428_1
  mkl                pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_637
  mkl-service        pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-service-2.4.0-py37h9ed2024_0
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_fft-1.3.1-py37h4ab4a9b_0
  mkl_random         pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_random-1.2.2-py37hb2f4e1b_0
  ncurses            pkgs/main/osx-64::ncurses-6.3-hca72f7f_2
  numexpr            pkgs/main/osx-64::numexpr-2.7.3-py37h5873af2_1
  numpy              pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-1.21.2-py37h4b4dc7a_0
  numpy-base         pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-base-1.21.2-py37he0bd621_0
  olefile            pkgs/main/osx-64::olefile-0.46-py37_0
  openssl            pkgs/main/osx-64::openssl-1.1.1l-h9ed2024_0
  pandas             pkgs/main/osx-64::pandas-1.3.4-py37h743cdd8_0
  pcre               pkgs/main/osx-64::pcre-8.45-h23ab428_0
  pillow             pkgs/main/osx-64::pillow-8.4.0-py37h98e4679_0
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-21.2.2-py37hecd8cb5_0
  pixman             pkgs/main/osx-64::pixman-0.40.0-h9ed2024_1
  py-boost           pkgs/main/osx-64::py-boost-1.73.0-py37hb2f4e1b_11
  python             pkgs/main/osx-64::python-3.7.11-h88f2d9e_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pytz               pkgs/main/noarch::pytz-2021.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  rdkit              rdkit/osx-64::rdkit-2020.09.1.0-py37h81f2deb_1
  readline           pkgs/main/osx-64::readline-8.1-h9ed2024_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-58.0.4-py37hecd8cb5_0
  six                pkgs/main/noarch::six-1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/osx-64::sqlite-3.36.0-hce871da_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/osx-64::tk-8.6.11-h7bc2e8c_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.37.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  xz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::xz-5.2.5-h1de35cc_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/osx-64::zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_3
  zstd               pkgs/main/osx-64::zstd-1.4.9-h322a384_0


Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate just_a_test_5
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/johanbr2/opt/anaconda3/envs/just_a_test_5

  added / updated specs:
    - rdkit


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  python_abi         conda-forge/osx-64::python_abi-3.7-2_cp37m

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  certifi            pkgs/main::certifi-2021.10.8-py37hecd~ --> conda-forge::certifi-2021.10.8-py37hf985489_1

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2021.10.26~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2021.10.8-h033912b_0
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1l-h9ed2024_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1l-h0d85af4_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: This is odd. Alternatively, one can try setting `CONDA_YES=True` at the beginning of the script. That should override the need for the `-y` flag. See `conda config --describe always_yes`.